# How to use multiprocessing pool with a list?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to make the following code parallel: [feret_diamater.py](https://gist.github.com/VolkerH/0d07d05d5cb189b56362e8ee41882abf)

When I call the get_min_max_feret_from_labelim() function with a labeled image (eg. 1000x1000 array, labels are numbers, between 0 and 1100), it calls the get_min_max_feret_from_mask() function for each label. As a result, get_min_max_feret_from_labelim() returns a list of 1101 elements. Works fine, but in case of a big image and many labels, it takes a lot a lot of time, so I want to call the get_min_max_feret_from_mask() using multiprocessing Pool.

The original code uses this:

```
for label in labels:
    results[label] = get_min_max_feret_from_mask(label_im == label)
return results
```

And I want to replace this part. I tried this after adding 'ncores' to the parameter list:

```
with Pool(ncores) as p:
    for label in labels:
        results[label] = p.map(get_min_max_feret_from_mask, label_im == label)
return results
```

But it is not working. How could I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `map` is the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map expects a list of arguments and returns a list of results:

```
with Pool(ncores) as p:
    result_list = p.map(get_min_max_feret_from_mask, [label_im == label for label in labels])
```

The returned list will match the order of the arguments list, meaning the first result is the result for the first label and so on.

Another option is to use `apply_async` to schedule tasks without blocking, this immediately returns an [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object allowing you to retrieve the results later. This one allows you to keep the original structure:

```
with Pool(ncores) as p:
    for label in labels:
        async_results[label] = p.apply_async(get_min_max_feret_from_mask, (label_im == label,))

results = {label: result.get() for label, result in async_results.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
with Pool(ncores) as p:
    return p.map(get_min_max_feret_from_mask, labels)
```

`Pool.map` takes the iterable (list or tuple, etc.) directly as the second parameter, no additional looping required:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map